# Need help writing an xpath string to match multiple, but not all, table cells

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping, web-scraping, minidom

Note: The question has been updated since some of the early answers were given. It's still the same question, just hopefully clearer.

I'm trying to get a site scraper working properly and I'm having problems coming up with a suitable xpath string for some table cells.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="Label" width="20%" valign="top">Uninteresting section</td>
    <td class="Data"> I don't care about this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Data"> I don't care about this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Label" width="20%" valign="top">Interesting section</td>
    <td class="Data"> I want this-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Data"> I want this-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Data"> I want this-n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Label" width="20%" valign="top">Uninteresting section</td>
    <td class="Data"> I don't care about this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="Data"> I don't care about this</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want the contents of all the Data fields in the interesting section.
There can be an arbitrary number of these. I don't care about anything else in the code, but I need all these.

In the example above:
 I want this-1
 I want this-2
 I want this-n

If it's relevant, I'm using xml.dom.minidom and py-dom-xpath with Python 2.7.

Comment: //tr[@class="Entry"]//tr... you are looking for a tr nested within another tr?

Comment: There's a table with more tables inside it, I left some of the structure out because I can already match it. My problem is with the section I posted above, I'm not sure how to get all the contents of the data cells in this specific section without getting them from other sections too. The contents of the label cell is the only thing that makes the sections different in terms of matching, the structure is the same for all the sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the n tds after the section (including other sections) with

```
 //tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text()
```

Then you can get all the m tds of the next sections that you don't want with

```
//tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class="Label"][1]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text()
```

and then you can use in Python the first n - m tds.

You could try to do the same in XPath with the position and count functions:

```
  //tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class = "Data"][position() <= (count(//tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text())  - count(//tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class="Label"][1]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text()) )]/text()
```

And if you had XPath 2.0 you could do it elegant with the `except` operator:

```
 //tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text() except  //tr[@class="Entry"]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Section title")]/following::td[@class="Label"][1]/following::td[@class = "Data"]/text()
```

Comment: I can't get the 3rd option to work and I don't have XPath 2.0, but the two first ones will do the job :) Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the (...)[...] construct in 3. requires already XPath 2.0. It might work, if the position check is moved before /text(). (I will edit it)

Answer (score 0):

```
//tr[@class="Entry"]/td[@class="Data"]/text()
```

Comment: That's no good, it won't restrict it to just the section I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
//tbody[tr/td[contains(text(),"Section title")]]/tr/td[@class="Data"]/text()
```

Updated. What this does:

1. Get `tbody` with `tr` with `td` that contains *"Section title"*
2. From those get texts of each `td` with c`lass="Data"`

Comment: Not exactly. This would only match the first cell, the other ones are not in the same tr. I've updated the code snippet in the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, but as far as I understand is that there are many _tbody_, in _tbody_ only the first row has "Label"

Comment: I've updated the snippet in the question, should be clearer now.